# Count number of values in a cell unless blank

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have a cell that uses a drop-down list that allows for multiple selections. How do I count the number of selections?

I used this:
=LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,",",""))+1

But this doesn't account for blank or no selection. How can I display 0 as well if there is no selection?

[image]

Comment: It counts the commas. If you have another way I would appreciate any that works.

Comment: Honestly I had no idea you could have a drop-down control return a comma separated list of multiple selections. ...a good example of why I like helping others here!...  Okay, so you want to avoid blanks - does that mean they are returned as consecutive comments?  `,,` ?

Comment: Do any selections have spaces? If not, substitute commas for spaces, trim the result then count for spaces as above with commas.

Comment: @jeeped they do not have spaces, can you please provide answer with how to do this?

Comment: ...and with your new example, what information do you  *need* from it?

Comment: @ashleedawg Currently that blank cell is 1, I need it to be 0. The formula I'm using is probably not the right approach. Looking for whatever works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your selections do not have spaces then substitute commas for spaces, trim the result then count for spaces as above with commas.

```
=LEN(trim(SUBSTITUTE(A2,","," ")))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(trim(SUBSTITUTE(A2,","," "))," ",""))+sign(len(a2))
```

Comment: @guybrianadams - that was a pretty easy fix; maybe could have been something you could have done.